# Multithreading Problem - Not understanding how the concept of printf implemented in concurrency

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, concurrency, pthreads, software-design

Im struggling a problem in multithreading which I have two threads running over one printf ; and I don't know how exactly those four cases that's already explained in that video are correct?! could anyone please illustrate more about them? appreciated for any help to understand why what's explained here to that problem is correct !
I'm attaching down the video of the problem:
[enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JT90KoarNjw)

Appreciated for any help for how those 4 cases of the problem are correct .

Comment: If _you_ "have two threads running..." Why don't you include the source for the code that those threads are executing in your question? That way, people still will be able to understand your question even if the video gets taken down.

Comment: Also note: That video is 37 minutes long. Nobody is going to spend that much time watching it just so that they can help you. You'll need to ask a short, concise question if you want to attract any attention here.